# C# bitmap comparison (PinvokeStackimbalance exception)

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap, pinvoke

I'm trying to compare two images using:

```
       [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
private static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, long count);

public static bool CompareMemCmp(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2)
{
    if ((b1 == null) != (b2 == null)) return false;
    if (b1.Size != b2.Size) return false;

    var bd1 = b1.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b1.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var bd2 = b2.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b2.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    try
    {
        IntPtr bd1scan0 = bd1.Scan0;
        IntPtr bd2scan0 = bd2.Scan0;

        int stride = bd1.Stride;
        int len = stride * b1.Height;

        return memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, len) == 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        b1.UnlockBits(bd1);
        b2.UnlockBits(bd2);
    }
}
```

I'm using the CompareMemCmp() like this (on_click event):

```
        Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\1.png");
        Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\1\2.png");

        if (CompareMemCmp(img1, img2) == true)
        { textBox1.Text = "Same"; }
        else { textBox1.Text = "Different"; }
```

Unfortunately an exception is thrown:

```
return memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, len) == 0;
```

**PinvokeStackimbalance**
"A call to PInvoke function 'TextRecognition!TextRecognition.Form1::memcmp' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature."

**what might be the problem?** I've already tried different methods to solve this problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pinvoke.net says the signature should be](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt.memcmp)

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, UIntPtr count);
```

Edit: pinvoke.net has labeled the original version of the declaration as x64 only, but it too seems to run fine on x32 with just an added `CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Comment: Error(even Before compilation): The best overloaded method match for 'TextRecognition.Form1.memcmp(byte[], byte[], System.UIntPtr)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: helped: [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, long count);

Comment: I've just modified second half of [import dll] based on you solution.. ;) thanks for the tip

Comment: @Alex You need to convert the parameters to the correct types, the page linked has an example. The length is a bit confuzzling, so wrapping the conversion in a private method is probably a good idea.

Comment: @Alex Ah, the Cdecl was enough, saves some type conversion magic :)

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson I'll mark your answer as correct, but the thing with Bytes threw an error..  nevertheless changing Byte[] to IntPtr will do the trick so the problem is now solved! thanks again

Comment: Alex byte[] would be fine if that's what you had. But since you have `IntPtr` then that's the most convenient for you.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what do you mean by "unless you run x64 only"? `UIntPtr` matches `size_t` on x86 and x64.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The referenced page at pinvoke.net explicitly states "C# Signature (x64 only)" on that version of the declaration. Always had good experience with following their advice, unsure why they labeled it as such though.

Comment: pinvoke.net is terribly innaccurate in my experience. Lots and lots of errors. That signature is fine on x86 and x64 because size_t is same size as UIntPtr.

Answer (score 2):

The signature should be:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, UIntPtr count);
```

The problems with the code in the question are

1. The mismatch between calling conventions: `msvcrt.dll` exports its functions as `cdecl`.
2. The count parameter is `size_t` in the native code which equates to pointer sized unsigned integer in .net, i.e. `UIntPtr`.